# What is BM in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

It's a term that seems to just have crashed in the LoL community. I now seem to see 'This play was so BM' or 'Look at the BM'... It seems to be only with cocky plays that went wrong.

So what is BM?

Comment: ^ I just realized it exists already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BM stands for](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/2bzoao/what_is_bming_whats_it_short_hand_for/) Bad Move/Manner/Mouth.

This term isn't exclusive to LoL and is used in quite a few games such as Hearthstone, Overwatch and just about any competitive game.

It's basically when you are being a jerk unnecessarily to someone. e.g "T-bagging" someone, leaving someone on 1 HP just to kill them anyway, taunting, etc.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense with the cocky plays gone wrong. Thanks!